# What is the role of a database in a redux application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to redux and I've just got my head around the architecture.

If we are keeping all our data inside a giant store, and that store is updated through actions which are all front end, what is the role of a back-end and database in a single page redux application?

Do you pull data into your store from a DB for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, redux store is just for storing temporary state in memory within browser. Back-end database is used to populate that Redux state. DB also can persist whole state of your application, where Redux store can't store full state of your application, because of memory constraints of the machine the browser is running on. DB is also needed to populate same state across different browsers/users of your application.

Said that there might be esoteric usages of Redux, e.g. on back-end or in browser with usage of WebRTC, where back-end database might not be needed.